# Eclipse Crashing While trying to launch it with hs_err_pid****.log SAPMachine 11.0.17 JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, crash, sapjvm

When trying to launch the eclipse its creating a hs_err_pid****.log file and crashing. This started after I upgraded the Windows to Win11 I'm using sapmachine-11.0.17 JDK
The content of the log file.

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffe3d789033, pid=10104, tid=18992

 JRE version:  (11.0.17+8) (build )
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.17+8-LTS-sapmachine, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [jvm.dll+0x1d9033]  protected: static void __cdecl ClassLoader::setup_boot_search_path(char const * __ptr64)+0x33

 No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

I was trying to launch the Eclipse IDE ( Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2022-06) it was crashing

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the JRE with all the optional Features set to Entire feature will be installed on the local drive solved this issue.
[JRE Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QH8v.png)